# How to restrict future date in android dialog API 5.0

Tags: android

In android version 5.0 date picker dialogue If we restrict future date using below code.

```
public class DatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

TextView dateText;

public DatePicker(final TextView dateText) {
    this.dateText = dateText;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datepicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
datepicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return datepicker;
}


@Override
public void onDateSet(final android.widget.DatePicker view, final int year, final int monthOfYear, final int dayOfMonth) {
    final String dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";
    final SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = form.parse(year + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        Log.d("DatePicker", e.getMessage());
    }
    final SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    final String formattedDate = postFormater.format(date);
    dateText.setText(formattedDate);
}
```

}

Future date's text colour are changed to grey but able to pick the date. How to restrict the date selection for future date in android 5.0.

Comment: can you put your datepicker full code?

Comment: I have updated my date picker code above